# .NET Module for Email to Database

Tags: sql-server, email, import, pop3

I'm looking for a robust module that will monitor an email account (ideally POP) and load each new email into a database (or cloud-based storage solution) as it arrives. This can either be an open source module, a commercial module or even SaaS. Ideally, would be easy to use from .NET.

Simply put, trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Do you know of any such modules or services? Did you have a positive experience with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [OpenPop.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/)? That won't automatically save it to a db, but you should be able to consume it from the POP3Client object.

Comment: Interesting as well. Would need to do more manual work than what I expected, but could be an open for POP only.

Comment: Chose this as the best answer, but both are acceptable solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Email2DB with some success.

http://www.email2db.com/

You can set up your own parsing rules for incoming e-mails and place data wherever you see fit as a result.

Comment: Interesting. Was looking more for a module than a standalone Windows app, but could solve my problem.